# X-Ray SDK tracing support for Quarkus Netty (Vert.x)

Tags: amazon-ecs, netty, quarkus, open-telemetry, aws-xray

I'd like to ask if there is any way to use tracing incoming requests with the X-Ray SDK for quarkus reactive (Netty) application?

To be more specific, I am trying to trace all hits to dynamoDB.

Following AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-filters.html) I can see solutions only for tomcat/spring.

Example solution is to provide bean for javax.servlet.Filter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public Filter TracingFilter() {
    return new AWSXRayServletFilter(SegmentNamingStrategy.dynamic("MyApp", "*.example.com"));
  }
}
```

Since Netty doesn't relay on servlets, is there any overcome available?

What I've done so far is adding:

1. **dependencies**:

```
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp")
implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-extension-aws")
implementation("io.opentelemetry.contrib:opentelemetry-aws-xray:1.+")
implementation("io.opentelemetry.contrib:opentelemetry-aws-xray-propagator:1.+")
implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2:2.8.0")
```

2. **properties**:

```
quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true
quarkus.opentelemetry.propagators=xray
quarkus.dynamodb.telemetry.enabled=true
quarkus.dynamodb.interceptors=com.amazonaws.xray.interceptors.TracingInterceptor
```

3. **config-code for idGenerator**:

```
import io.opentelemetry.contrib.awsxray.AwsXrayIdGenerator
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.IdGenerator
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

class AwsOpenTelemetryIdGeneratorProducer {

    @ApplicationScoped
    fun idGenerator(): IdGenerator {
        return AwsXrayIdGenerator.getInstance()
    }
}
```

4. **aws-otel-collector definition in terraform for aws_ecs_task_definition**:

```
{
      name : "aws-otel-collector",
      image : "public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:latest",
      cpu : 0,
      portMappings : [],
      essential : true,
      command : [
        "--config=/etc/ecs/ecs-xray.yaml"
      ],
      environment : [],
      mountPoints : [],
      volumesFrom : [],
      logConfiguration : {
        logDriver : "awslogs",
        options : {
          awslogs-create-group : "true",
          awslogs-group : "/ecs/ecs-aws-otel-sidecar-collector",
          awslogs-region : "eu-central-1",
          awslogs-stream-prefix : "ecs"
        }
      }
    }
```

5. **IAM policy**:

```
statement {
    actions = [
      "xray:PutTraceSegments",
      "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
```

With this configuration I am able to trace requests for my ECS. The problem is I cannot trace any dynamoDb hits as following exception occurs "**Suppressing AWS X-Ray context missing exception (SegmentNotFoundException): Failed to begin subsegment named 'DynamoDb': segment cannot be found.**".

Exception's message is quite meaningful, it cannot determine any parent-segment for DynamoDb sub-segment, what is understandable.

So I decided to add following **vertex.core.Handler**:

```
import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRay
import com.amazonaws.xray.contexts.SegmentContextExecutors
import com.amazonaws.xray.entities.Segment
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection
import io.vertx.core.Handler
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext

@RegisterForReflection
class XRayTracingFilter : Handler<RoutingContext> {

    override fun handle(context: RoutingContext) {
        val request = context.request()
        val segment: Segment = AWSXRay.beginSegment("TestSegment")
        segment.putHttp("request", request.method())
        SegmentContextExecutors.newSegmentContextExecutor(segment)
        context.addEndHandler { segment.close() }
        context.next()
    }
}
```

which then I register as follows:

```
import io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.filters.Filters
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes

class XrayConfig {

    @ApplicationScoped
    fun registerFilters(@Observes filters: Filters) {
        filters.register(XRayTracingFilter(), 1)
    }
}
```

After adding XRayTracingFilter exception SegmentNotFoundException doesn't occur anymore but unfortunately I'm still unable to see any tracing coming from **AWS::DynamoDB::Table** node. All I still see comes from **AWS::ECS::Fargate**.

I cannot understand at this point why the problem still occurs and which part of my configuration it is related to. Is it a problem with Otel-collector, my Handler or IAM policy?

**STACK INFO**:

- Quarkus 3.6.6
- Java 17 Corretto
- Gradle 8.5

I would be super glad for any feedback/ideas for my issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Netty itself doesn't have OpenTelemetry instrumentation on Quarkus. The tracing is done at the vert.x layer. DynamoDB is not instrumented in Quarkus but in the otel-aws instrumentation lib that is not tested in Quarkus.
What spans are you hopping to generate? Spans with the queries to Dynamo?
You can always use `@withSpan` or do custom instrumentations on the methods calling the DB.